# How can I achieve graphql/dataloader like behaviour in AppSync?

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync, dataloader

I am currently building an AppSync API and after doing some research into how to load four different fields with two data sources (two fields per data source) I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67426948/5719079).

The response to this question seems to do a great job explaining the use of data loaders and using mostly field resolver. The problem is that in AppSync I can't use tools like [graphql/dataloader](https://github.com/graphql/dataloader) which would allow me to deduplicate for example multiple get requests to the same DynamoDB item.

Then I thought maybe something like this is built into AppSync natively but after trying and looking at the traces it seems to not be doping any deduplication work and just does the dumb call to the DynamoDB table for each field, although they use the same key.

No I was wondering if there is a way to achieve this without borderline writing it myself in a pipeline resolver?